# VUE, VUETIFY |How to hide the selected radio option(selected in first group) from the second radio group if both radio groups have same radio options?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, radio-group

[Click on this link to see the IMAGE, I want GSTN1 option hidden from the second radio group since it is getting selected in the first radio group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IrRhI.png)

```
       <template>
        <v-radio-group v-model="firstIdRadio">
          <v-radio
            v-for="n in firstIdArr"
            :key="n"
            :label="`${n}`"
            :value="n"
          >
          </v-radio>
        </v-radio-group>
        <v-radio-group v-model="secondIdRadio">
          <v-radio
            v-for="n in secondIdArr"
            :key="n"
            :label="`${n}`"
            :value="n"
          ></v-radio>
        </v-radio-group>
      </template>

      <script>
        data() {
          return {
            firstIdRadio: "",
            secondIdRadio: "",
            firstIdArr: [GSTN1, GSTN2, GSTN3],
            secondIdArr: [GSTN1, GSTN2, GSTN3],
          }
        }
      </script>
```

I am using the Vuetify v-radio-group tag to populate radio buttons, I want the option hidden in the second radio group which got selected in the first radio group. If we take reference to the image provided above, GSTN1 should be hidden from the second radio group as it is selected in the first radio group.

Big thanks for the help.

Totally blank as to how to approach the challenge. The major issue is to know how to conditionally populate the radio options in the second radio group as per the selection done in the first radio group. Since I am using Vuetify, I am stuck on this part.

Comment: You can use either a computed property (which will filter the second group of radios to remove the selected one) or directly filter inside the template.

Answer (score 0):

[Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```html
<v-radio-group v-model="secondIdRadio">
  <v-radio v-for="n in secondIdArr.filter(i => i !== firstIdRadio)" :key="n" :label="`${n}`" :value="n"></v-radio>
</v-radio-group>
```